# IS there any way to create tasks in particular Channel of teams using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph, graph-api, ms-graph-client, office-graph

**I want to create a spfx webpart to create a tasks in the teams channel**

**IS there any API for creating tasks in teams channel**

**Below is the image of my channel Task tab**

[image]

**I am new to Graph API Thanks in advance**

Comment: Do you want to create planner tasks or to-do tasks? Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todotasklist-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) & let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Please check the updated question with image teams channel task where i want to create task using Graph APII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below endpoint to create new task inside any planner.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks
```

Request body

```
    {
  "planId": "xqQg5FS2LkCp935s-FIFm2QAFkHM",
  "bucketId": "hsOf2dhOJkqyYYZEtdzDe2QAIUCR",
  "title": "Update client list",
  "assignments": {
    "fbab97d0-4932-4511-b675-204639209557": {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment",
      "orderHint": " !"
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you noticed what you need is to find a plan Id for that particular channel's planner and its bucket id

Below are the steps you can follow to get

To get Plan Id -
Open the planner in a particular channel and click on the website icon, this will open the planner in the browser and in the end, you will find the plan id

[image]

To get bucket ID

We would have to make the below API call

```
/planner/plans/{plan-id}/buckets
```

This will list down all the buckets inside the plan and you can find bucket id.

Use both above information to make actual create task call as mentioned in above step.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks it worked
But how can we create task with others fields like (attachments ,Due Date,StartDate,priority) options in the request body

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannertask?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties - you can find here properties name which you can send.

Comment: I don;t see way to add attachment but would have to check if that works